# Travelling to Romania to explore family roots?

Tags: census-records, vital-records, romania, research-travel

I will be traveling to Romania this spring for about a 2 week stay. Aside from enjoying the tourist side of things, family history exploration will be a priority. I will have a Romanian tour guide with me to assist with translation.

My grandfather's village was Pojorta, near Fagaras city. My grandmother, on the other hand, was from Bukovina, from the village of Burla near Radauti, in the north east part of the country.

What is the probability that I would be able to access records such as censuses, birth and marriage from the period of roughly 1875 to 1910 in these small villages, or the nearest city or town for those villages?

First off, would those records even exist and 2nd, where would they likely be held?

Your response to this would be of much value to me in planning the amount of time I'd need for this research.

Comment: Romania can be difficult to get records from.  I've heard stories of people going there with all the relevant documentation and being turned away.  I believe there are central archives, meaning that the records would not be in the villages, though there might be other records there.  I'm making this a comment, not an answer, because I don't have enough experience to confirm what I've heard.

Comment: Posorta, Fogaras county (now Pojorta, Romania) was in Hungary, so there were civil registrations starting Oct. 1, 1895. These were done in two copies: the original register-book was kept at the local registrar's office (which was in Posorta), the duplicate was sent to the county archive. I have no idea what Romania has done with these records, and whether they're accessible anywhere.

Comment: Before 1895 (and usually existing after, as well), you'll need church registers. The local church in Posorta was Greek Catholic, and Roman Catholics were recorded in Fogaras. Bishop's/archive copies were required in most denominations starting in the 1820s, but again, I haven't a clue about the fate and current ownership of church registers in Romania.